# var functionOne = (function(){})() vs. var functionTwo = (function(){}())

Tags: javascript

What is the exact difference between these two lines of code.

```
 var functionOne = (function(){})();
```

and

```
 var functionTwo = (function(){}());
```

I've noticed that both were being used while looking through js Module pattern, but i'd like to know what is exact difference between them.

Comment: AFAIK, they're equivalent

Comment: there is no defference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the same **Immediately-Invoked Function**.
There few different syntax variations. As Douglas Crockford’s JSLint offers the right declaration for self-invoking functions is:

```
(function () {
    //body
}());
```

Alternative syntax is, which Crockford calls “dog balls”…:

```
(function () {
    //body
})();
```

Comment: But that's just his opinion. They mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Calling that declaration the *right* declaration is itself not right :) That's personal preference

Comment: the first one is more readable and therefore preferable. when a coder sees the enclosing parens, they know to work back to the left to figure out what's being called. with dogballs, there's a potential that it's a returned function being invoked instead of the wrapper. everything else equal, readability is right.